# Duplicate a string inside a file and overwrite another using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to batch edit a multiple line M3U file with sed with content like the following:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="NBC.us" tvg-name="NBC US" tvg-logo="http://example.com/NBC.us.png" tvg-chno="12" group-title="United States",NBC
```

I'd like to find/replace so that I end up with something like the following:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="NBC.us" tvg-name="NBC" tvg-logo="http://example.com/NBC.us.png" channelid="12" group-title="United States",NBC
```

In other words, I need to find/replace `tvg-chno` to `channelid` AND copy the string from (and not including) the last `,` to the end of the line and use it to overwrite the contents of `tvg-name`. I have a sed command working for the first bit and a broken one not quite working as intended for the second as follows:

```
sed -i 's/tvg-chno/channel-id/g' test.m3u    
sed -i 's/\(.*tvg-name="\)\(.*"\)\(.*",\)\(.*\)/\1\4\3\4/g' test.m3u
```

The second sed command outputs:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="NBC.us" tvg-name="NBCUnited States",NBC
```

I was hoping to be able to get all the transforms done in a one-liner if possible.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Always add your expected output too in your posts in code tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid grabbing too much as the old value, the second command should be:

```
's/\(tvg-name="\)\([^"]*\)\(".*",\)\(.*\)/\1\4\3\4/'
```

To combine the two commands into one, just join them with a semicolon:

```
sed -i 's/.../.../g;s/.../.../' test.m3u
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(tvg-name=")[^"]*(".*)tvg-chno(.*,([^,]*))$/\1\4\2channelid\3/' file
```

Pattern match on the strings and use back references to achieve the required result.

N.B. this assumes that`tvg-chno` will always follow `tvg-name`, if not, two substitutions will be needed.